# Two tier Bootstrap 3 Nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What would be the best method to create a Bootstrap 3 Navbar that I have drawn up below?

[image]

I'm looking to have the logo full height and for the bottom blue nabber to have a 45 degree angle. The top navbar will just contain font awesome icons for social media.

Comment: Link to JSFiddle of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/ncta7e9x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can accomplish this: wrap your navbar links inside a new div while also separating your icon links (upper part) from the text links (lower part) so they can still function with the default mobile toggle.

Then you can simple create a split between the upper and lower sections by adding `width: 100%` to one section.

As far as the **angled** part of the lower nav section, you can use pseudo elements with border rules to accomplish this: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) for more info.

Here are two examples depending on what you're ultimately trying to do: one full-width and one inside a `container`.

**Example 2: Full-width**

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 50px solid #069CCF;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 50px solid #069CCF;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split .navbar-upper {
    padding-left: 0;
    float: right;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split .navbar-lower {
    background-color: #069CCF;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-upper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-upper > li {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-lower {
    padding: 0 0 15px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-lower > li > a {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/70x70/FA05D5/fff">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-split">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-upper">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-lower">
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
    galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Example 2: Container width**

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 50px solid #069CCF;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 50px solid #069CCF;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split .navbar-upper {
    float: right;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-split .navbar-lower {
    background-color: #069CCF;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/70x70/FA05D5/fff">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-split">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-upper">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-lower">
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
    galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. Is there any way to bleed the nav-bar lower of to the right of the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean to be honest.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean having the lower Nav-bar in blue go to the right outside the container?